# SqlException ErrorCode returns -2146232060 instead of 26 (Can't find server instance)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to handle an exception I know its ErrorCode is 26, but it does not return the right integer, giving me -2146232060.

[Screenshot of QuickWatch with the exception description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKgj0.png)

So instead of writing this:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
    if (e.ErrorCode == 26)
    {
        //my code
    }
}
```

I have to use this:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
    if (e.Message.ToUpper().Contains("ERROR: 26"))
    {
        //my code
    }
}
```

Why is it returning -2146232060 and how can I get 26 so I don't need to compare all that string values?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Markus Deibel sorry, I wasn't clear enough, so I edited it at the end of the second code snippet :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlException ErrorCodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531369/sqlexception-errorcodes)

Comment: @MarkusDeibel This is not at all a duplicate of that question. Please read the question before making assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want to be looking at is SqlException.Number (which is SQL's error number) and not SqlException.ErrorCode (which is the SQL driver error number).

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Sandbox;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("throw 50000, 'oops', 1;", connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode + ": " + ex.Number + ": " + ex.Message);
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Errors[i].Number + ": " + ex.Errors[i].Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    };
}
```

... yields ...

```
-2146232060: 50000: oops
50000: oops
```

Much more information about SqlException on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx%22MSDN%22) and about the specific error you are receiving [here](https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/System-Data-SqlClient-SqlException-0x80131904%22here%22).